# USB2.0 to HDMI Adapter

Tags: usb, hdmi

I am getting a USB2.0 to HDMI Adapter because I only have one HDMI plug for my monitors on my laptop.  Can USB 2.0 handle HDMI vs. USB 3.0 or will quality suffer ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the maths yourself: Wikipedia has the [required data rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI#Refresh_frequency_limits_for_standard_video) for various HDMI resolutions.

Wikipedia again tells you [USB 2.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#USB_2.0) has 480 Mbit/s. 720p HDMI already requires 720 MBit/s.

So the only way you can have an USB 2.0 to HDMI adapter is by using some kind of compression. And it'll get worse at higher resolutions.

You can live with this for mostly static screen content (browsing the web). For movies and games, not so much.

Comment: The keyword here is "DisplayLink". https://www.displaylink.com/corporate/how

Comment: It's not the "keyword", it's one proprietary compression scheme.

Comment: So would you say that HDMI at 480MB/s is the same as DVI in terms of resolution ?